# Assembly 8086 printing a signed single-digit integer

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I wrote a program to get the smallest number in an array, 
but I can't print it on the screen :((
I think the problem is converting it to ASCII.

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
    x db 0,5,-1,4,2     ;my array
    min db 0            ;variable to store the smallest number
    msg db "The min number is: $"
.code
main PROC
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax

    xor cx,cx
    mov cl,5          ;set count to 5

    mov si,0          ;start at index 0
L1:
    mov dl,x[si]     ;can't compare memory to memory so I moved x[si] to dl
    cmp min,dl       ;checks to see if the value in dl is smaller than 
                     ;value in min
    JNB no          
    mov min,dl       
no:
    inc si
    loop L1
    mov ah,09
    mov dx,offset msg    ;print the message
    int 21h

    cmp min,0            ;check if number is negative or positive
    JB minus

    mov ah,02
    mov dl,min
    int 21h

minus:                 ;if minus print the minus sign
    mov ah,02
    mov dl,'-'
    int 21h

    *mov ah,02
    mov dl,min
    or dl,30h        ;here's my error can't print value of min
    int 21h*

    mov ah,04ch      ;exit code
    int 21h
main ENDP
END main
```

Also if anyone has good source or a book of learning 80386 assembly protected mode please mention it here :))

Comment: Questions on how to print integers in x86 assembly have already been asked lots of times, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bassembly%5D+print+number

Comment: emu8086 has built in debugger AFAIK (never used it myself, I mean the whole emu8086). Consider exploring it, as your find_min code has several shortcomings even if printing would work. Printing out decimal value is actually lot more tricky, either constraint yourself to values 0-9 only first, to make the algorithm work, or don't print anything and use only debugger to verify results directly in memory/registers. When you will get over basics, search for that value -> decimal ascii string examples, or start with hexa first, those are much easier to understand (the code of conversion).

Comment: Thank you guys a lot, I haven't coded in assembly in a while I forgot about the method of converting numbers to ascii .

Comment: I think the title of this qiestion should be "How to print negative number in 8086 assembly"

Comment: emu8086 (I assume the tag is correct) also has macros for printing numbers. `print_num` (for signed) and `print_num_uns` (for unsigned). More on their usage can be found here: http://jbwyatt.com/253/emu/asm_tutorial_05.html

Comment: @Ahtisham: I think you're right, the dup-target I used only does unsigned.  Your answer here only handles single-digit numbers, but I guess that's all this question needs.

Comment: @PeterCordes Should the duplicate mark be removed then ?

Comment: @Ahtisham: I couldn't find another question about printing negative numbers (other than `printf` of course), so reopening.

Comment: @PeterCordes I believe it is Sep Roland has a version that does signed numbers. (main difference is the check for the sign bit and the addition of a negative sign). I haven't searched but I know it exists. Edit: found it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42325964/unable-to-display-negative-numbers-using-array-in-the-following-8086-assembly-co

Answer (score 1):

You code has two problems ( apart from displaying a negative number )

**1.Placing zero in NUM variable**

What if your array contains non-zero numbers like for eg: `5, 4, 7, 1` it should print 1 as its the minimum number but your code will print 0 which is not even present in the array.

**2.Using JNB and JB Instructions**

These Instruction are only used for positive integer here have a look [JNB](http://www.electronics.dit.ie/staff/tscarff/8086_instruction_set/8086_instruction_set.html#JNB) [JB](http://www.electronics.dit.ie/staff/tscarff/8086_instruction_set/8086_instruction_set.html#JB). You have to use [JNG](http://www.electronics.dit.ie/staff/tscarff/8086_instruction_set/8086_instruction_set.html#JNG) and [JG](http://www.electronics.dit.ie/staff/tscarff/8086_instruction_set/8086_instruction_set.html#JG) as your array contains negative number.

Following is the program to check for minimum number in an array ( Doesn't matter if it contains negative or positive number it will work in both the cases and it also shows how to print negative number ):

```
    .model small
.stack 100h

.data

        num db 7,5,3,4,2      ;my array
        msg db "The min number is: $"               

.code

main PROC

         mov ax,@data
         mov ds,ax
         mov ax, 0
         mov bl, num [0]  ; store first element of array in bl
         mov cx, 4
         mov si, 1        ; index of second element

         calMin:

                mov al, num [si] 

                cmp bl, al       
                jng continue  ; jng is used for signed numbers

                mov bl, al      ; exchange values if smaller

                continue:   

                       inc si       

                loop calMin 

         mov ah, 09h
         mov dx, offset msg
         int 21h        

         mov cl, bl

         neg cl         ; 2's complement the min number ( to check if its negative or positive number )                         

         js posNum      ; jmp to posNum if sign flag is set

         mov bl, cl
         jz posNum                       

       negNum:

         mov ah, 02h
         mov dl, '-'     ; print minus symbol if negative number
         int 21h

       posNum:

         mov ah, 02h     
         mov dl, bl
         add dl, 48
         int 21h  

         exit:                                    

                mov ah,04ch      
                int 21h

main ENDP

END main
```

Comment: BTW, you don't need to `xchg bl,al`, you can just use `mov bl,al` which is more efficient.  Also, `js`/  `jz` to the same destination is silly: you want to jump if `cl` is now less than or equal to zero, and `neg cl` sets flags according to `0 - cl`, so `jle posNum`.

Comment: After printing a `-`, you can just `mov bl, cl` and fall through into `posNum` instead of duplicating the code to print a single-digit integer.

Comment: @PeterCordes that is what i am trying to do :) but it prints `/` because i am placing the complement of number in bl and printing it when array contains all non-zero positive numbers.

Comment: placing `mov bl, cl` in between `js posNum` and `jmp negNum` two  work for negative and positive number but not for zero it prints `-0`

Comment: Then you put it in the wrong place.  It should be in a block that's jumped over for non-negative numbers.

Comment: have to include `jz posNum` i don't find any other way.

Comment: Use `jle` or `jge` instead of `js` jump on ZF or SF (actually `SF != OF`, but we know `OF` = 0 after `0 - x`.  Actually, `0 - 128` does overflow, but that's not a single-digit number.)

Answer (score 1):

Related: on a modern x86 CPU in 16-bit mode, you can use SSE4.1 `phminposuw` with a range-shift to make it work on signed inputs.  You can find the min out of 8 elements in one instruction: [x86 Assembly - 2 largest values out of 4 given numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40229202/x86-assembly-2-largest-values-out-of-4-given-numbers).  Load signed bytes using `pmovsxbw xmm0, [num]`.

---

A more-efficient way to implement the min-finding loop avoids the [slow `loop` instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742570/why-is-the-loop-instruction-slow-couldnt-intel-have-implemented-it-efficiently), and avoids taken branches (other than the loop branch) when there's no new min.  I could have made the code smaller by using `loop`, and/or by using a normally-taken `jge` to skip over an instruction inside the loop, instead of falling through into code that's normally not run.

Related: [Assembly program that finds second largest value in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47466116/assembly-program-that-finds-second-largest-value-in-array/47467682#47467682).  I used a similar loop structure there.

Comparing against an end-pointer is efficient, whether it's a constant or in a register.  As an immediate, it saves instructions outside the loop.  We also don't need to tie up `CX` with a loop counter; we already have the pointer in `SI`.

The main point of this answer is the **more compact code for printing a leading `-`**, [like I mentioned in comments on @Ahtisham's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43593748/assembly-8086-printing-an-integer/47479638?noredirect=1#comment81920768_47479638).  See the 2nd part of `main` below.

```
.model small
.stack 100h

.data
        num db 0,5,-1,4,2      ;my array
        numEnd:
        numSize = numEnd - num

        msg db "The min number is: $"               

.code
main PROC
         mov   ax, @data
         mov   ds, ax

         mov   si, OFFSET num
         mov   bl, [si]          ; bl = min

  calMin:                      ; do {
           cmp  si, OFFSET numEnd-1
           jae  endloop          ; if (p >= end-1) break;
           inc  si               ; p++

           cmp  bl, [si]
           jle  calMin           ; if (*p <= min) continue;  signed compare

           ; on new min, fall through and update BL before continuing
           mov  bl, [si]         ; min = *p
           jmp  calMin         ; } while(1);

  endloop:

      ;;; BL = min.  Do whatever you want with it.
```

Now we have the min of the array in `bl`.

Normally you'd load into a register instead of using multiple loads, but `mov al, [si]` only runs rarely for most inputs.  Reloading the same value is fast (because of cache) so saving an instruction in the common-case loop is a win even if it means an extra load when we find a new min.

Given a **single-digit** signed `min` in `bl`, we can print it (with a `-` if it's negative):

```
          ; we could print the message before the loop
          ; if we wanted to avoid clobbering registers.
         mov  ah, 09h         ; print a message first
         mov  dx, offset msg
         int  21h         ; al = write string to stdout(ds:dx)

         mov  dl, bl    ; in case it's positive
         neg  bl        ; bl = 0 - bl   setting flags accordingly
         jle  posNum    ; if (0 <= num) skip the leading '-'

         mov ah, 02h
         mov dl, '-'     ; print minus symbol if negative number
         int 21h         ; al = print char to stdout(dl)

         mov  dl, bl    ; the negated value is positive, print it

     posNum:
         ; absolute value of single-digit number in DL
         mov ah, 02h
         add dl, '0'
         int 21h       ; al = print char to stdout(dl)

     exit:
         mov ax, 04c00h      ; AL = 0 (exit status), AH = 4C (Exit function)
         int 21h
main ENDP
END main
```

You don't need to test `SF` and `ZF` separately with separate `js` and `jz` instructions.  I used `jle` after a `neg` to fall through if the original number was negative, because it sets flags based on `0 - num`.  i.e. `jle` is taken if `0 <= num`, i.e. `num` is non-negative and we shouldn't print a `'-'`.

I could have done

```
 test bl, bl
 jge  posNum
```

because [`test same,same` sets flags identically to `cmp bl, 0`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33721204/test-whether-a-register-is-zero-with-cmp-reg-0-vs-or-reg-reg/33724806#33724806).  And of course `jge` is taken for numbers that are greater than or equal to zero.

Note that `0 - 128` does overflow, so just testing SF after `neg` isn't equivalent to `jle`.  `jle` is correct, `js` isn't.

But our printing only handles single-digit integers in the first place.  If that's what you have, use one of the many multi-digit number functions to print the absolute value as an unsigned integer after printing the optional `'-'`.